# How to add bordercolor for textfield in UITableviewCustomCell - iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to validate the text in textfield which is added in customtableview cell. I could get the text and validate, but couldn't set the border color. I tried even reloading the whole tableview. Thanks in advance.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.selectedRow inSection:0];
MyCustomTableviewCell *cell = (MyCustomTableviewCell*)[self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UITextField *textField = cell.txtfield;
self.string = textField.text;

if (self.string.length < 8)
{
    textField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    self.showTxtFieldinRed = YES;
}
else
{
    textField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    self.showTxtFieldinRed = NO;
}

NSArray *indexPathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.selectedRow inSection:0]];

[self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCustomCell";
     MyCustomTableviewCell *cell = (MyCustomTableviewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     cell.delegate = self;
     cell.txtCVV.delegate = self;

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *arrayContent = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomTableviewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    cell = (MyCustomTableviewCell*)[arrayContent objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
if(self.selectedRow == indexPath.row)
{
   cell.txtfield.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
}
else
{
   cell.txtfield.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this out ......

```
cell.comment_txt.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
[cell.comment_txt setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
cell.comment_txt.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from UITextField and override drawRect method.